# How to use Assert\File and Assert\Image at the same time in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to validate a file upload with 2 conditions:

> 1. Only allowed to upload image file or PDF file
> 2. Max width with Image file is 160px and no requirement with PDF file

I used "Constraints" of Symfony but when I upload a PDF file, it said that

> This file is not a valid image.

Because I used both Assert\Image and Assert\File at the same time, so it will check whether the file is image or not first.

But **What I want** is that when I upload a file, it will check Assert\File first. If it's an image, then it will check Assert\Image. How can I do?

Here is my code at Entity:

```
   /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="ad", fileNameProperty="imageFile")
     * @var File
     * @Assert\File(
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/svg+xml"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "You can only be allowed to upload Image file or PDF file"
     * )
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     maxWidth = 160
     * )
     */
    private $image;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
#[Assert\AtLeastOneOf(
    constraints: [
        new Assert\File(extensions: ['pdf']),
        new Assert\Sequentially(
            [
                new Assert\File(extensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg','png','svg']),
                new Assert\Image(maxWidth: 160)
             ]
        ),
    ]
)]
public UploadedFile $file;
```

Comment: From symfony 6.2: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#extensions

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create Custom Validation constraint and check there for type of file or image with your custom logic.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to check this in an form-event

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

private $validator;

public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Add the fields

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (// check mimetype of $data['image'] is an image) {
            $imageConstraint = new Assert\Image(['maxWidth' => 160]);

            $errors = $this->validator->validate($data['image'], $imageConstraint);

            if ($errors) {
                /** @var ConstraintViolation $error */
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    $event->getForm()->get('image')->addError(new FormError($error->getMessage()));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```